# Change version of PHP which CLI uses on CloudLinux VPS

Tags: php

I have a CloudLinux VPS where accounts are running *ea-php72*.

I am trying to install *Drupal* using *Composer*, which requires the php extension *fileinfo*.

The extension is installed, confirmed as loaded in *ea-php72* with a php info page in a browser. But CLI seems to use *alt-php72*. I've added `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` to the php ini files, but running `php -v` gives the following:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_fileinfo.dll' (tried: /opt/alt/php72/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll (/opt/alt/php72/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/alt/php72/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll.so (/opt/alt/php72/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_fileinfo.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Is there a reason CLI runs *alt* instead of *ea* PHP - can I tell it to use *ea-php72*, or failing that how do I install *fileinfo* in *altphp-72*?

Comment: Unless I've completely misunderstood you should try `extension=php_fileinfo.so`. Because `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` is for PHP running on Microsoft Windows

Comment: Thanks Philip - I've made that change and it's gotten rid of the PHP warning from `php -v` - which presumably means PHP can see the extension OK now, except running `php -m` doesn't list fileinfo as an enabled module, and Composer still says `fileinfo is missing from your system` - I guess this isn't a Linux question any more though, so may have to ask this somewhere else now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the answer to the question in the title, was to disable the account in *CageFS* - this for some reason returns the CLI to use the same PHP as web, so it went to ea-php72, and therefore had the *fileinfo* extension available. No idea why this is the case, it was the solution given me by CloudLinux support.

I'm the only one with access to the VPS, so don't think it's a security risk, I will however re-enable account in CageFS once I've done what I need to just to be sure.